# Grails: Use results of Criteria + projections as a filter on the original table

Tags: grails, hibernate-criteria, createcriteria

I have the following table/model:

```
class Post {
  int id;
  String comment;
  static belongsTo = [category_id:Category];
}
```

I wish to create a query that can filter out the last `Post` (highest `id`) per `Category`. I want the results in `List<Post>` form.

In other words (I believe) in SQL the query would look as follows:

```
SELECT *
FROM
  Post AS source
  JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(id) AS id, category_id 
    FROM Post
    GROUP BY category_id
  ) AS filter
  ON source.id = filter.id;
```

If I understand correctly, the first step is to use a `HibernateCriteriaBuilder`:

```
def c = Post.createCriteria();
  def results = c.list {
    projections {
      groupProperty("category_id", "myid")
      max("id", "version")
    }
  }
```

So my question is a two part:

1. Am I on the right track?
2. How can I use the results object to obtain a `List<Post>` array?

   (Something like: `def latest = Post.FindAllByXXX(result);` )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you are on the right track. I would also add the *id* property for the Post to my projections:

```
projections {
    property('id')
}
```

and then collect all Posts using the *id* to get a list of posts, something like:

```
def latestPosts = results?.collect{Post.read(it[0])}
```